# Why am I getting "relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against '.text'" when assembling a tiny program?

Tags: assembly, gcc, mingw-w64

I'm currently following a course on x86 assembly programming with AT&T syntax. We were instructed to setup WSL and use gcc to assemble our code, but for a bonus assignment I want to write a Windows application. I thought the easiest way to do that would be to install mingw-w64 through apt, and use the gcc from that to make an exe, which can be run either in windows directly or through WSL.

However, whenever I try to compile the following file with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o test test.s` in WSL, I get an error saying `relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32S against '.text'`. From what I found online, I can prevent the error by changing the `mov` instruction on line 12 with `movabs`, but then the program still doesn't work when I run it.

test.s:

```
.text
hello:      .asciz "Hello World!\n"

.global main

main:
    push    %rbp
    mov     %rsp, %rbp

    mov     $0, %rax
    mov     $hello, %rdi
    call    printf

    mov     %rbp, %rsp
    pop     %rbp

end:
    mov     $0, %rdi
    call    exit
```

This exact code works perfectly fine with regular gcc, so I don't know where to go from here. I'd massively appreciate some help with getting this to work, since programming in assembly is quite new to me. Preferrably also without the `movabs`, I think that should be possible right?

Later, I also want to include some of the windows include files so I can create a window and draw to it etc., but getting my code to work at all is more important right now.

Comment: Change `mov $hello, %rdi` to `lea hello(%rip), %rdi` to use relative addressing.

Comment: That compiles, but just like the movabs variation it still doesn't print the message.

Comment: With the suggested change from `mov` to `lea`, it assembles `as -o hello.o hello.s` and links `gcc -o hello hello.o -no-pie` without any errors.

Comment: MinGW is a toolchain that makes Windows executables.  `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` *in WSL* is probably a cross-compiler that runs on Linux but makes Windows executables.  (Oh, I see that's what you intended.)  As such, I'd expect it to link with a standard library that uses the Windows x64 calling convention, with the first arg in RCX, and requiring you to reserve 32 bytes of shadow space.  (Your current code is for the x86-64 System V calling convention used on Linux, where the first arg is passed in RDI, and AL needs a count of the number of FP args in XMM regs.)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! My code works now! Might you also have any idea how i can include Windows.h, except the assembly variant instead of the C variant? I've found online how to do it with MASM, but I'm not sure that mingw even has those windows related files.

Comment: @FlorisvanOnna: Didn't see your reply until I just happened to look at this again, since you didn't @ notify me.  If you have a header that *only* has `#define`s, you can `#include <foo.h>` in your `.S` file (asm with CPP), like Linux `#include <asm/unistd.h>` to get Linux syscall-number macros.  But if a header also has C / C++ prototypes or other stuff that isn't valid asm syntax, you need to extract the macro definitions from it with something like `gcc -E foo.h -dM` to dump the macro definitions, IIRC.  And anything that's not a CPP macro, you need to port manually.